# Does Postgres copy command optimise the data export of huge number of rows from a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, export-to-csv

I am trying to export huge data (10 million) meeting specific criteria from a table into a csv file. I want to run the command in a shell script and write the output to a file. The script will be run on a live database. So the export should not impact the application.

"Copy" command seems to be one of the option along with plain "Select" statement. As per my understanding from documentation "Copy" command optimises data upload. I want to know if it optimises export process and hence has less impact on the database. Is there any other better option to export huge data meeting certain criteria?

I am from developer background with not much database experience. So requesting for an advise in this scenario.

Comment: Your choice of `copy` is right, it's made and optimised precisely just to handle this type of operation. If it's just a one-off snapshot or a dump that you'll load to another postgres instance or use later with this one, [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) offers a dedicated fast, compact and compressible output format, if you're not limited to csv. It will actually issue a `copy`, just specifying a different format and handling it internally.

Comment: The faster it runs, the more load it will put on the IO system, and so the more it will impact competing IO intensive activity.  It seems like you want the opposite of optimized, if you are concerned about minimize IO competition.

Comment: @jjanes: Thank you for your quick response. My understanding is that "Copy" command is not IO intensive and may be taking a bit more time. However it will have not have sharp/spiky overhead on the database. Is it correct?